# How can I make Google Optimize variant to wait until everything is loaded?

Tags: asynchronous, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

I got a Google Tag manager - Google Optimize environment in my React APP. 
When I start my experiment on google Optimize the variant is applied but as soon as the translations are applied everything goes back to the regular page.

This is because of the asynchronous process of i18n,

The page loads
 The variant is applied
 The internationalization is applied
 The variant changes are discarded

Is there any way to ensure that the variant won't be changed?

Comment: Do you have an event or a callback available, when the internationalization is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible you can choose to add an event in the code to trigger the optimize experiment after the internationalization occurs something like the below, then in Google Optimize choose load experiment on custom event.

`dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate'});`